# Как вырезать выделенную область на изображений Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Подскажите как мне вырезать выделенную область в Opencv.
На данный момент выделяется область и я хочу что бы все лишнее удалилось.
Белый фон.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Код:

Это все что смог сделать, пытался еще выделить контуры всех объектов и удалить все меньше чем основной текст (нужно оставить только 9 цифр )

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread("57.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU|cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(threshed, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((2,2)))

cnts = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

nh, nw = img.shape[:2]
for cnt in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = bbox = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if h < 0.4 * nh:
        continue
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)


cv2.imshow("gray", img)
#cv2.imwrite("dst.png", img)
```

Comment: pillow не подойдет?

Comment: Через него например, указать какую область не трогать а остальное удалить как то?